# Trouble with expressing "anything" using patterns?

Tags: pattern-matching

Suppose I have a list:

```
L = {p, p \[Implies] q}
```

I want to create a function that I can apply to L (`f/@L`) such that whenever x is in L and `x \[Implies] anything`, then append `anything` to L. I think this function would be something like:

```
f[x_] := If[MemberQ[L, (x \[Implies] _)], AppendTo[L, _], Nothing]
```

But I'm having trouble expressing the "anything".

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of way, but be warned that we'll need to fix some ambiguities in your question and we'll need to determine whether you really need mutation side-effects:

```
L = {p, p \[Implies] q};

f1[x_] :=
  With[
    {matches = Cases[L, x \[Implies] _]},
    Join[L, Last /@ matches]]

f1[p]
(* {p, p \[Implies] q, q} *)

f1[q]
(* {p, p \[Implies] q} *)
```

Now, if `L` were this:

```
L = {p \[Implies] q, p \[Implies] r}
```

then

```
f1[p]
(* {p \[Implies] q, p \[Implies] r, q, r} *)
```

but only if `L` had been defined thus prior to defining `f1`. If you don't want that constraint, then we need to add our list-that-might-contain-implications as an argument to `f1`. Also, this doesn't actually change `L`, it just returns a list that contains the elements of `L` and the new elements we want to add. If you need to actually change `L` then we'd need to add that bit of functionality.

Now, if you don't need the results appended, but just added somewhere in the returned list, you could do this:

```
f2[x_] := L /. (x \[Implies] y_) :> Splice[{x \[Implies] y, y}]

f2[p]
(* {p, p \[Implies] q, q} *)
```

or if we had a different `L`:

```
L = {p \[Implies] q, p \[Implies] r};
f2[x_] := L /. (x \[Implies] y_) :> Splice[{x \[Implies] y, y}];
f2[p]
(* {p \[Implies] q, q, p \[Implies] r, r} *)
```

Again, the sequence of evaluations matters, so the same questions from above need to be resolved.

To be clear, this doesn't actually answer your question exactly. I don't know how to resolve the questions and also don't know what aspects of your question are important. For example, you say you want to use the function like `f/@L`, but maybe that was just an idea you had and not a true requirement. Also, you said you wanted to know "how to express 'anything' using patterns", and I didn't really answer that directly or explicitly. So, if your question is really a deeper pattern-matching question that goes beyond this example, then we'd need to expand the discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) and named [`Pattern`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pattern.html) with [`RuleDelayed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RuleDelayed.html) if you are not too concerned with the point of insertion in the list.

```
f[x_, lst_] := lst /. h : (x \[Implies] j : _) :> Sequence[h, j]
```

then

```
l1 = {p, p \[Implies] q};
f[p, l1]
```

> ```
> {p, p \[Implies] q, q}
> ```

and

```
l2 = {p, p \[Implies] q, t \[Implies] c, p \[Implies] s, p \[Implies] s};
f[p, l2]
```

> ```
> {p, p \[Implies] q, q, t \[Implies] c, p \[Implies] s, s, p \[Implies] s, s}
> ```

Hope this helps.